# filter each object type from one column and do it by yearly dates that are in another column

Tags: r

I have a column where I need to filter by type of accident and check within the year column, when each type appears during the 13 years of the database.

I tried to use a function that separated each type of accident but generated a new database by month of each year separately

Comment: It's difficult to help you without a reproducible example. https://xiangxing98.github.io/R_Learning/R_Reproducible.nb.html However, I will group by accident and year and then will count number of rows in each group.